# Why does spark not recognize my "dataframe boolean expression"?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

## Environment

- `pyspark 2.1.0`
- `python 3.5.2`

## Problem

I have a join with multiple conditions:

```
join_cond = [
    (col("ltmr1.anc_ref") == col("global.anc_ref") &
     col("global.straight_distance") >= args.radius_1 &
     col("global.straight_distance") <= args.radius_2)
]
```

Which is used later on:

```
ltm_r1_in_r2 = data_with_straight_distance.alias("global") \
    .join(
        less_than_min_r1.select(
            col("anc_ref"),
            col("num_rep")
        ).alias("ltmr1"),
        join_cond,
        "leftsemi"
)
```

The program fails at the following line:

```
col("global.straight_distance") >= args.radius_1 &
```

Where `args` is the tuple from `argparse`.

Relevant stacktrace:

```
  File "/mnt/mesos/sandbox/full_load.py", line 114, in full_load
    col("global.straight_distance") >= args.radius_1 &
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 635, in __nonzero__
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Why is spark not recognizing my condition and how should I correct it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has the expected output:

```
join_cond = [
    col("ltmr1.anc_ref") == col("global.anc_ref"),
    col("global.distance") >= args.radius_1,
    col("global.distance") <= args.radius_2
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting each conditional statement inside parentheses

```
join_cond = [
    ((col("ltmr1.anc_ref") == col("global.anc_ref")) &
     (col("global.straight_distance") >= args.radius_1) &
     (col("global.straight_distance") <= args.radius_2))
]
```